# Cant send image attachments with email using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using a nodemailer to send a mail. Now I want to that the user be able to send an attachment (image with the email. I have tried several ways but nothing worked for me. Even looking here but still hard to figure out how it works. So any help would be great.

So here is my contactPage form

```html
<form onsubmit="return phonenumberValidation()" method="POST" action="send">
                <p>
                  <label>Naam</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Organisatie</label>
                  <input type="text" name="company">
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" required >
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Telefoonnummer</label>
                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
                  <span id="messages"></span>
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                  <label>Bericht</label>
                  <textarea name="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>
            </form>
```

And here is my code

```html
app.post('/send', (req, res) =>{
    const output = `
        <p> You have a new contact request</p>
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
        <li>Image: ${req.body.image}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;
    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'host',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'user', // generated ethereal user
      pass: 'password', // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  
  let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <email of sender>', // sender address
    to: 'email', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Test ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: output, // html body
    image: req.body.image,
    attachtements: [
        
        {
            fileName:     req.body.title+".jpg",
            streamSource: fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path)
        }
    ]
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
      console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  });
  

  res.render('contactPage', {
      message: 'We hebben uw aanvraag ontvangen en we zullen u binnen twee werkdagen beantwoorden'
  });
```

Iam getting the following error as wel

```html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
    at app.post (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\app.js:149:49)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:343:9)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\w_ema\MTaarten\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:75:10)
```

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/  check out this documentation

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for the quick response. I have looked to the link. But still not clear what to use if I want to upload attachment (image) and send it with the email.

Comment: the error looks like it is pointing to the image in your output object.   is there an image uploaded in that field?

Comment: This is my output jon const output = `
        <p> You have a new contact request</p>
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
        <li>Image: ${req.body.image}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>

Comment: yes, but req.body.image is what is.coming back undefined

Comment: Yes this is something which is still not clear. If look into the documentation of nodemail.com/message/attachments then this should work for me  {   // file on disk as an attachment
            filename: 'text3.txt',
            path: '/path/to/file.txt' // stream this file
        }, but still not clear how to define the path/to/file.txt

Comment: Where does `streamSource` come from? It's not in the docs

Comment: And `fileName` should be `filename`

Comment: Hi Daniel, according to the documentation if I want to send an attachment from disk. So this sould be the code:  {filename: 'text3.txt',path: '/path/to/file.txt'} // stream this file. But I still dont know how to configure the path? and the filename is text.txt. I want to send an image so its jpg. Still unclear.